# Any ideas why the files are corrupted when downloading via PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

i can upload and download but the file that i download is corrupted. the type of files that im testing the download on is Word Document.

My codes a follows in downloading:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
include 'Library/opendb.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
$query = "SELECT name,type,size,content "."FROM filetble WHERE id = '$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query,$con) or die('Error, query failed');
list($name, $type, $size, $content) =   mysql_fetch_array($result);

header("Content-length:$size");
header("Content-type:$type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");

echo $content;
include 'Library/closedb.php';
exit;
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Table:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filetble` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumblob NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Comment: Please post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE filetbl` - I suspect you use a text column instead of a blob column.

Comment: Look into the output that you're getting.

Comment: Please sanitize `$_GET['id']` with [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval): `$id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : die('error')`! See also: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Off-topic, but having your database store files it probably not the best idea. Instead, you should add a database entry associated with a file in your file system to save the overhead from having your DBMS serve the file.

Comment: How are you saving the file? I also agree with @KristianAntonsen that you're better off storing a file path as opposed to the content itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are echoing more than just the content of your document : you first have this :

```
echo $id;
```

And only then you have :

```
echo $content;
```

If you echo more than only the content of your document, chances are pretty high that you don't output a valid word document => remove that first `echo`.

If this doesn't help, an idea would be to take a look (using an hexadecimal editor, for example) at :

- the file you are expecting to get *(what's in the `content` field in your database)*,
- and the actual content you receive

You might find there are some differences ; spaces at the beginning, for example ?

If no difference... well, are you sure that what you have in your database is 100% correct ?

Comment: Is there no risk of `echo` mangling the binary output? Also, opendb != closedb. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. nothing changed

Comment: `echo` is the standard way of outputtin *stuff*, even if it's binary content *(for example, I've used it many times to output images, which are binary data)*.

Comment: you mean spaces in the file that i uploaded? or the file that will be downloaded? okay, i'll use hexadecimal editor.

Comment: @bzlm thanks for the comment, I've edited my answer to remove that ;;; @Christian I meant spaces before an opening `<?php ` tag, for example, that would get sent in the output.